# Editing function in source code using input

Tags: function, dynamic, mfc, drawing

I am creating a program which is very similar to "WolframAlpha" using `MFC`. Is there any way I can easily read a function from an `EditBox` and edit my function inside my source file depending on it? Or is there any other way to save a function? Thank you a lot.

In addition, I have to draw this function. Should I do it by drawing many lines? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can read anything from an edit box, but that gives you a text string not a mathematical function. Your C++ source file is not part of the running program so editing that does not make sense. To turn the input string into a mathematical function that can be executed would require you to write a compiler or interpreter.